# Capture built-in CMD command execution using Sysmon

Tags: windows, event-log, event-viewer

When I run commands like ping, gpupdate or any commands that creates a process, Sysmon captures it under Event ID 1 but it doesn't log anything if I run the CMD built in commands. Any idea how can I configure Sysmon on a Windows machine to detect the built in commands runs?

Answer (score 0):

For PowerShell you can turn on Script-Block Logging, Sysmon can't monitor such operations just like he can't monitor clicks inside a GUI